# SQL reset row_number when previous id column null

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is hard to explain so I will give an example.
I need SQL (ms server), I assume its with row_number over partition but can't get it to work.

I have this table:

| ID | PreviousID | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | a |
| 2 | 1 | b |
| 3 | 2 | c |
| 4 |  | d |
| 5 | 4 | e |
| 6 |  | f |

I want these results:

| ID | NewID | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 1 | b |
| 3 | 1 | c |
| 4 | 2 | d |
| 5 | 2 | e |
| 6 | 3 | f |

And another with just the new IDs of each sequence:

| NewID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | f |

Instead of a row number new id, it could also have the first id of the sequence, whatever is easier, as long as it identifies the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want a windowed `COUNT` of rows where the value of `PreviousID` is `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PreviousID IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NewID,
       Data
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: This works, thanks. How do I get the last table, basically the first of each newid?

Comment: [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) @CoolkcaH .

Comment: When I try a row_number over that I get an error "Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."

Comment: You'll need to use 2 CTEs, @CoolkcaH .